# Does $A/πA \otimes_{o/πo} V＝A \otimes_oV$ holds for DVR $A$ and uniformizer $π$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a DVR with uniformizer $π$. Let $O$ be DVR with uniformizer $π$.
Let $V$ be $R$-module and $πV＝0$ (so $V$ is a module over $O/πO$).
Then, **does $A/πA \otimes_{O/πO} V＝A \otimes_O V$ holds** ?

I guess this is true, but I'm stuck with proving this. Base ring changes, so I cannot use exact sequence like argument.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I haven't thought about it in this case, but it is absolutely wrong that you can't ever use exact sequence like arguments when you have change of base rings.  Change of base is a tensor product, and tensor products are right exact, which automatically gives you half of exactness in general for free.  But tensor products are sometimes exact (when a module is "flat"), and sometimes you have that the implication goes both ways (when a module is "faithfully flat").  Sometimes, even when you don't have general theory to help you out, you can still set up an exact sequence and do a diagram chase.

Comment: What do you mean by the ring of integers of a DVR?

Comment: Your question has many problems (what is $R$, is $A$ a $O$-module, $O=o$ ?). If $\pi V = 0$ then $\otimes_O V = \otimes_{O/(\pi)}V$, no need of DVR or whatever.

Comment: Why two functor coincidences ?